# How to check if my app has been configured battery optimized on Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm wondering if there's any way in React Native that allows us to know if user has been selected "Battery Optimized" for our app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in native android,You can use [`PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(java.lang.String)) boolean to determine if an application is already ignoring optimizations ie whether the app is on the whitelist .

```
 @ReactMethod public void isAppIgnoringBatteryOptimization(Callback callback){
    String packageName = getReactApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      callback.invoke(pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName));
    }else{
      callback.invoke(true);
    }
```

and then in js

```
 isAppIgnoringBatteryOptimization: function(callback) {
    jobModule.isAppIgnoringBatteryOptimization(ignoringOptimization => {
      if (ignoringOptimization != null) {
        callback("", ignoringOptimization);
      } else {
        callback("error", null);
      }
    });
  }
```

https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job/ is a good library that sees all the edge cases of background execution

If you want to ask user to turn it off - ask for

`Manifest.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission

from

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Comment: not related to the answer- if you do request this permission and fire it in your app,it can be banned from the google play store(google has been doing this since 2015). just checking and warning the user of it is ok though